# asp.net horizontal menu using web.sitemap xml - remove submenu icon

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

I created horizontal asp:menu using that control and it created successfully but I do not want to have submenu right error icon (which comes from webresource location).

How can I remove that icon or disable that icon?

Comment: What is your code? What hve you tried?

Comment: Its done.. StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"

Answer (score 0):

Its done.. `<asp:menu StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"...`